# LINQ to SQL (Executing Custom SQL Expressions) : how to substitute a parameter with an array value

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Usage of method:

```
DataContext.ExecuteQuery<TResult>(String, Object[]);
```

The following generates an `InvalidOperationException` with message:

> {"Could not format node 'Value' for execution as SQL."}

```
int[] ids = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
context.ExecuteQuery<SourceTarget>(select c.* from Customer c where c.customer_id in {0}, ids);
```

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using LINQ-to-SQL, you could use the LINQ syntax instead of ExecuteQuery, eg:

```
var customers = from c in context.Customers
                where ids.Contains(c.customer_id)
                select c;
```

Or, if you insist on making it a SQL query, try:

```
context.ExecuteQuery<SourceTarget>(String.Format("select c.* from Customer c where c.customer_id in ({0})",
    String.Join(",", ids)));
```